# How to reference another table with two different types of keys

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I have a table that has an int id. I have another table that references it but used a string to represent the id instead of an int without using foreign keys.

In nhibernate how to I reference a table with a key of int to a table with a column representing it as a string?

I know the table is messed up but it was inherited and cannot be changed.